# ¿Cómo corregir este error al tratar de crear una base de datos con microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2022

Realizando el siguiente procedimiento, haciendo uso de SQL Server 2022 Express Edition Y SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), luego usando el método TranTransact-SQL para crear una base de datos dando clic derecho en *New Query* (que significa Nueva consulta en español) y luego en la ventana que se generó, copiando este código:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [BDBanco_Estudiante]    Script Date: 13/03/2023 4:17:34 p. m. ******/
CREATE DATABASE [BDBanco_Estudiante]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante.mdf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'BDBanco_Estudiante_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante_log.ldf' , SIZE = 8192KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 65536KB )
 WITH CATALOG_COLLATION = DATABASE_DEFAULT
GO
```

luego ejecutandolo; haciendo clic en el boton *Execute* que es *Ejecutar* en Español , sale el error:

> MMsg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
> Error al buscar el archivo 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\BDBanco_Estudiante.mdf' en los directorios, error del sistema operativo: 3(El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.).

Para solucionar ese problema traté de averiguar ¿cómo crear el archivo de extensión mdf que pertenece a mi base de datos?

Buscando en youtube: "*how to create the mdf extension file that belongs to a database?*", que quiere decir lo mismo que busqué en youtube en español (con la excepción de que dice la parte final de esa misma pregunta que hice en youtube: "a una base de datos" en vez de lo que dice la pregunta anterior a esa, que es lo que busqué en youtube: " a mi base de datos"), y lo único que encontré en youtube que solucionaba esa pregunta fue esto: *¿Cómo crear archivo de instalación con un adjunto de base de datos .mdf con prueba en c# en windows application en visual studio?*. Debido a que era la única idea que tenía sobre como solucionar el problema, no pude solucionar el problema ya que ese video no explica cómo crear los archivos de extensión .mdf de las bases de datos.

¿Alguien podría explicarme cómo saber de qué manera crear un archivo mdf acorde a como se hace una base de datos?

Comment: No funciona así. No se trata de crear el archivo mdf, sino que la instrucción Create Database, es la que se encarga de realizarlo, pero te da la posibilidad que mediante `FileName` le digas donde se tiene que alojar el archivo que va a crear. Por defecto Create Database genera dos archivos que conforman una base de datos estandar SQL Server. El Mdf, donde se alojarán los datos, y el ldf donde se guardan las transacciones. Realmente se pueden hacer más archivos, pero toda base de datos consta al menos de 1 mdf y 1 ldf. El error te indica que probablemente no tiene acceso a esa carpeta.

Comment: Muy probablemente en tú disco c no exista esta ruta: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL16.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\` y create Database no la va a crear.

Comment: Mismo comentario que en la pregunta cerrada. Si el usuario, es decir usted, no garantiza que existan la totalidad de los directorios anidados representados por la ruta utilizada en la ejecución de la consulta dada sobre el programa SSMS, no será posible para la aplicación el llevar a cabo la tarea solicitada debido a que esta está imposibilitada de crear todo un árbol de directorios a pedido del usuario (de nuevo, usted). Así pues, dése a la tarea de revisar que el entorno de ejecución de su actividad es propicio y adecúe la ruta al mdf antes de ejecutar la consulta.

Comment: PD. Le recomiendo no usar tamaño máximo unlimited. Cuando pasa de 30GB he visto casos en los que comienza a comportarse de forma inesperada, por lo que personalmente prefiero tener archivos de hasta 30GB y, si es necesario, añadir archivos nuevos al filegroup

Comment: Si es express, no puede tener una base de datos mayor a 10GB. Por otro lado, nunca había visto eso de los 30GB

Answer (score 0):

El error es relativamente claro.

> El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada.

Eso puede significar 2 cosas: La ruta no existe o SQL Server no tiene acceso a la ruta.

Al ser un código copiado de internet (y por la ruta) es muy probable que tu estrucura de carpetas sea distinta a esa ruta. Lo más aconsejable es que designes una ruta específica para crear tus bases de datos y organizarla de una manera eficiente. Para aprender es aceptable esa ruta, pero para ambientes productivos te recomiendo buscar mejores prácticas que incluyen usar discos distintos para datos y log, así como arreglos de discos.

Por último, es importante señalar que la ruta es desde el servidor y no desde el cliente. Ambos pueden ser tu computadora local, pero eso no siempre será el caso.